# how to get the new target element after replaceWith in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to find each target element in iframe on click event. Below is the code that I used. I am using this function to style each target element on click. This function is used to change the heading style.

Suppose i have a `h3` tag in the iframe. When clicking on the `h3` tag I need to change heading option based on radio button.  After changing the radio button i have replaced the tag h3 with other heading tags like h1,h2,h3,h4 based on the radio button value. But the issue is that initially my target object is h3, after changed the radio button my target also changed.

How can I solve this issue by replacing the target object?

```js
var getElement = function() {
  $('[data-edit="froala"]').on('froalaEditor.initialized', function(e, editor) {
    var $div_tag = $('[data-edit="froala"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body');
    $div_tag.on('click', function(e) {
      var element_name = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
      var $target_class = $('[data-target="' + element_name + '"]');
      trigger_object(e, element_name);
    });
  });
}

var trigger_object = function(e, element_name) {
  $('[data-style="size-style"]').off('change').on('change', function(event) {
    if ($(this).data('css') == 'heading-size') {
      if (this.value == 'jumbo') {
        var html = $(e.target).html();
        var $a = $("<h1>" + html + "</h1>");
        $(e.target).replaceWith($a);
      } else if (this.value == 'headline') {} else if (this.value == 'subhead') {} else if (this.value == 'small_subhead') {}
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span6 wid_options">
  <input type="radio" name="heading_size" value="jumbo" data-attr="heading-size" data-style="size-style" data-css="heading-size">
  <p>Jumbo</p>
</div>
<div class="span6 wid_options">
  <input type="radio" name="heading_size" value="headline" data-attr="heading-size" data-style="size-style" data-css="heading-size">
  <p>Headline</p>
</div>
<div class="span6 wid_options">
  <input type="radio" name="heading_size" value="subhead" data-attr="heading-size" data-style="size-style" data-css="heading-size">
  <p>Subhead</p>
</div>
<div class="span6 wid_options">
  <input type="radio" name="heading_size" value="small_subhead" data-attr="heading-size" data-style="size-style" data-css="heading-size">
  <p>Small Subhead</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, nor what your question is

Comment: There is something unclear in your code. You are first checking for data-css which should have the 'heading-size' value. This is always the <input>. Then you continue to check for the value attribute which should contain 'jumbo' as a value. However, this is inside a paragraph tag, and not the input?

Comment: @GabeHiemstra thanks for the reply. The issue is that suppose initially the target object in iframe is h3. so i get the target object as h3 using e.target event. so after changing the radio button this target is changed as  h2, h3 ,h4 like that. so how can i get the new target

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited my question. Now you clear my question?